# Async Fetch Being Called More than Once By Detail Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a master-detail component (basically the master is a list of links ([WordList](https://github.com/mrarthurwhite/Project5/blob/master/rc-wordlist/src/components/functional/WordList.js).js encapsulating [Word](https://github.com/mrarthurwhite/Project5/blob/master/rc-wordlist/src/components/container/Word.js).js) and the detail is a details display component ([WordDisplay](https://github.com/mrarthurwhite/Project5/blob/master/rc-wordlist/src/components/container/WordDisplay.js).js in the repo).

When I click on a word in *Word*.js (part of the master component) I would like to see the details listed in the detail component ( *WordDisplay*.js ).

**The concern/question:**

What is the best life cycle method for making asynchronous fetch calls whenever the detail component is refreshed?

The detail/display component  (*WordDisplay*.js) receives a wordId from the master component ( *Word*.js ) and the detail/display component uses that *wordId* to make a fetch to the back end (the [ror API](https://github.com/mrarthurwhite/Project5/tree/master/api-wordlist)).  The concern is that there are at least two calls being made presently when there should be just one call. I suspect that it has to do with the life cycle method I am using and how I am using it (I am presently using *componentDidUpdate( prevProps )*)

**What I tried:**

I would like the detail component (*WordDisplay*.js) to change whenever the `wordId` changes. When there is a change in this `wordId` I make an async fetch call. The place to check for this change: I tried different life cycle methods but presently I am using `componentDidUpdate( prevProps )`. Please see line 13 of ([WordDisplay](https://github.com/mrarthurwhite/Project5/blob/master/rc-wordlist/src/components/container/WordDisplay.js).js in the repo).

I previously tried fetching in ( *componentDidMount*() ) but that caused the display to update only once (for obvious reasons (I am new to react), it mounts once and then does not necessarily re render).

The concern is that presently I am trying *componentDidUpdate( prevProps )* but it is making *two* requests, one more than necessary. I am wondering what life cycle method I could use and how.  I am going to try  *shouldComponentUpdate* but unsure.

Improving my understanding:
I suspect this has to do with my understanding of React-Redux. To patch up my understanding I was hoping for pointer to resources or book recommendations, please.

p.s.
Code:  https://codeshare.io/29WPDV

The entire src is here : https://github.com/mrarthurwhite/Project5

an overview of the  working project https://youtu.be/7-ChB1Ik8ec

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please include in your question any relevant code referenced via link. A link to the repo is ok bout shouldn't be the primary way of accessing the code you have issue with.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks! I just added the links to the relevant files and some sample code. Hope that is sufficient.

Comment: Just taking a glance through your repo it appears as though redux-thunk is in play and working, so it seems the action should work when the component mounts. Have you ruled out your server/API inconsistently returning results?

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks Drew, I have been working extensively on the application since last and I have updated the question and the repo slightly. Now the fetch is working but it is being called more than once (when it should only be called once).  I did not want to just leave the question that was sort of resolved up there so just recycled the post. Hope that is ok.

Comment: It's a bit hard to mentally trace through the code, but I think the initial issue is that you don't start by directly comparing previous & current `props.match.params.wordId`, i.e. "the route changed, go fetch a word". IMO you've got too much tangled in with just computing if you need to fetch or not. Also, many times you'll need to fetch data when the component mounts, and possibly again later if things change, like a route prop, and the component never unmounts, as is the case when you use the render prop of a `Route. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-render-methods

Comment: @DrewReese I do directly compare previous and current `wordId`. If you notice [WordDisplay.js](https://github.com/mrarthurwhite/Project5/blob/master/rc-wordlist/src/components/container/WordDisplay.js) line 13. You say I would need to fetch data when the component mounts (where would I make the fetch request for when it mounts? in `componentDidMount`?) More importantly , how would I fetch if a route prop changes and the component never unmounts? a route prop like `wordId` for example (that being the entire point of my original post).Presently I check change in `wordId` in `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: `props.word.id` isn't the same prop as `props.match.params.wordId`, they update independently from each other, and are at least one render cycle separate (because `word` is updated *after* fetch in a reducer), more if *any other* state or prop update triggers another render. Yes, it is typical to fetch data initially on mount and again on update. Did you read the docs I linked? It explains inline usage and difference between the `component` and `render` prop, specifically for `render`: "This allows for convenient inline rendering and wrapping without the undesired remounting explained above."

Comment: @DrewReese I just tackled the newId condition check (and you are right).  I did read the docs you linked but they are perhaps the LEAST userfriendly API docs I have ever encountered. Clicking on the methods does not work scrolling leads to confusion (which code is what?) . I did not read the line you quoted. I have updated the repo and did it right before/around when you posted this. Thanks! How can I thank you?

Comment: Yeah, some docs are more difficult to parse through, I've spent *a ton* of time in the react-router-dom docs (almost have it perma-opened in a browser tab). Post up your answer and mark it accepted.